# Call javascript function with bind

Tags: javascript, function, binding

I have the function:

```
$(this.myObject).click(A.bind(this));
function A(){
     //  stuff here
}
```

I want to call from within a second function (binding this).

```
$(this.myOtherObject).click(B.bind(this));
function B(){
      A();             //  works but does not bind
      A.bind(this);    //  does not work
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: bind does not call/execute the method....

Comment: Please check the MDN documentation for bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind . If you want to **call** the function, either use `.call` or `.apply`, by providing `this` as the first argoment of either two. Otherwise, use `.bind`, then call the function explicitely.

Comment: this.myObject belongs to global window object?

Comment: bind() return a function to be executed later. let X = A.bind(this); X();

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [call(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) not bind() since bind() just returns the method.

```
A.call(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function B(){
    A();             //  works but does not bind
    A.bind(this);    //  does not work
}
```

`bind` is for creating a new function bound to a context (see [bind documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)). If you go that way, you would need to call the new function :

```
A.bind(this)();
```

However, you should rather use [call method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which will directly call the function with a specific context :

```
A.call(this);
A.apply(this);
```